# Is there facebook api for finding all the users that register through my app

Tags: android, facebook

I wrote an app in android and i want to know for a specified user what is the  list  of his facebook's friends that submitted through my app .
like the list of draw something .
is there an api for that ?
how can i use it ?
i know how to get the list of friends's id , pic , name .....
but i want only the friends that use my app .

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();    
bundle.putString("fields", "name, picture");
String response = facebook.request("me/friends", bundle);
```

can any body help me with that ?
i will appreciate that very much.
thanks .

Comment: possible duplicate of [GetAppUsers using c# opengraph sdk?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7956639/getappusers-using-c-sharp-opengraph-sdk)

Comment: (same api call, different SDK)

Answer (score 1):

Easy, just add the "installed" field to your query:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();    
bundle.putString("fields", "name, picture, installed");
String response = facebook.request("me/friends", bundle);
```

If the user has your app installed you'll have:

```
{
    "installed": true, 
    "id": "USER_ID",
    "name": "USER_NAME",
    "picture": "USER_PIC_URL"
}
```

Otherwise:

```
{
    "id": "USER_ID",
    "name": "USER_NAME",
    "picture": "USER_PIC_URL"
}
```

Comment: thank you very much .  i tried it but i cannot find all my friends in the response the string of the friends ends like this "{"name"..."

Comment: do you know how can i get the full list of my friends ?  i cannot miss some friends.

Comment: Read the official blog post about [How-To: Paging with the Graph API and FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/)